# Spring Security SAML2 service provider - RelyingPartyRegistration.entityId() vs RelyingPartyRegistration.assertingPartyDetails(c -> c.entityId())

Tags: spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

Small question regarding Spring Security SAML2 please.

To narrow the scope, the question is regarding:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-service-provider</artifactId>
<version>5.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I am coming from an older version, where API are deprecated.

The new version of RelyingPartyRegistration seems to have two entityId, which confuses a bit, which one is which please?

```
      return RelyingPartyRegistration.withRegistrationId(registrationId)
                .entityId(entityId)
                .assertingPartyDetails(details -> details.entityId(entityId)).build();
```

Looking at this piece of code, entityId is present twice.

What are the differences please?

Thank you

Comment: One is the entity ID for the relying party (your Spring application) and the other is the entity ID for the asserting party. You may find this SAML diagram useful https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-saml2login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RelyingPartyRegistration.withRegistrationId(registrationId) .entityId(entityId)`

represents the entity id registered on the identity provider. It is the identifier the identity provider knows your app.

The `.assertingPartyDetails(details -> details.entityId(entityId))` is the url of the entity provider website.

Answer (score 1):

A little clearer:

1. The entityId provided to the RelyingPartyRegistration builder, withRegistrationId(registrationId).entityId(entityId), is the service provider entity ID, which will be written into the SAML assertion by the identity provider (IdP) as the audience. This value needs to be configured on the IdP. Remember, at this point you are configuring the side of the "relying party", which is the SP.
2. The entityId in the assertingPartyDetails (which means the IdP) is the entity ID of the IdP. The SP checks this in the assertion to make sure the assertion comes from the expected IdP. This is provided to the SP via the metadata (if you get that for configuration) or manually copied to the SP.

Be careful with the previous answer: the entityId for the IdP is not usually a valid URL for the IdP, it simply is a unique identity value provided by the IdP that is often in the form of a URI or URL.